# How can I implement a dotrine entity event listener

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-4.4

I'm working with Symfony 4.4, at first I want to check my doctrine version I found:
in composer:

```
doctrine/orm": "^2.4.5
```

in symfony.lock:

```
"doctrine/orm": {
    "version": "v2.7.0"
},
```

which one I have to trust ?

So the main problem is that I'm trying to implement a doctrine entity listener but It didn't work for me:

## App\Entity\Admin:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\AdminRepository")
 *
 * @ORM\EntityListeners({"AdminListener"})
 */
 class Admin implements UserInterface
```

## services.yaml:

```
admin_listener:
    class: App\EventListener\Doctrine\AdminListener
    tags:
        -
            name: doctrine.orm.entity_listener
            event: preRemove
            entity: App\Entity\Admin
            method: preRemove
            connection: 'default'
```

## App\EventListener\Doctrine\AdminListener:

```
namespace App\EventListener\Doctrine;
use Doctrine\Persistence\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;

class AdminListener
{
    public function preRemove(Admin $admin, LifecycleEventArgs $event)
    {
        dump($admin);
        dd($event);
    }

}
```

## console:

```
>bin/console debug:event-dispatcher doctrine.orm.entity_listener
#output:                                                                        
 [WARNING] The event "doctrine.orm.entity_listener" does not have any     
           registered listeners.
```

Comment: [Listening on an entity with an entity listener](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/faep/listening-on-an-entity-with-an-entity-listener) - I don't think you need a `services.yaml` entry at all. Looks like you need to use `Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs` instead.

Comment: I'm getting this exact same issue. They simply do not work at all. I've tried with a services.yaml entry, with the annotation on the Entity, with annotations inside the supposed Listener. Nothing. The handler functions are not fired. This feature is just utterly broken.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem that I had a DataPersister ( API Platform component ) that disallow the Delete before that attempt the Doctrine level, so for that I thought that the event listener is not working.
Otherwise, the event listener is working and there is many alternatives to make it:

https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/doctrine/events.html